# Triggering a window reload on tab change to update the tab contents in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, local-storage

I am creating a dashboard application, and I want to use multiple tabs so that multiple dashboards can be used at the same time and navigated via the tabs with an initial welcome screen. I currently have it so that when adding additional tabs, they render the  component with a different ID for each tab. When switching between tabs, I am having to force the reload of the page via window.location.reload(false) within the handleSelectTab handler in order to update the tab contents. While this works, it is very clunky and takes a second to reload the page - is there a better way of doing this that does not mean I have to force the reload of the page everytime the tab changes?

Code for my Dashboard page:

```
const id = uuid()
  const username = localStorage.getItem('username')
  const userDashboards = () => {
    if (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(getUserDash(username+1))) === null) {
      return ({
        tabs: [{id:'Welcome Page', name:'Guide to Use', content:'Welcome Dashboard'}],
        currentTab: {id:'Welcome Page', name:'Guide to Use', content:'Welcome Dashboard'},
        editTabNameMode: false
      })
    } else {
      return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(getUserDash(username+1)))
    }
  }
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(userDashboards);


  saveUserDash(username+1, state)

  const handleDoubleClick = () => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      editTabNameMode: true
    });
  };

  const handleEditTabName = e => {
    const updatedTabs = state.tabs.map(tab => {
      if (tab.id === state.currentTab.id) {
        return {
          ...tab,
          name: e.target.value
        };
      } else {
        return tab;
      }
    });

    setState({
      ...state,
      tabs: updatedTabs,
      currentTab: {
        ...state.currentTab,
        name: e.target.value
      }
    });
  };

  const handleOnBlur = () => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      editTabNameMode: false
    });
  };

  const createTabs = () => {
    const allTabs = state.tabs.map(tab => {
      return (
        <li>
          {state.editTabNameMode && state.currentTab.id === tab.id ? (
            <input
              value={tab.name}
              onBlur={handleOnBlur}
              onChange={handleEditTabName}
            />
          ) : (
            <button
              className={state.currentTab.id === tab.id ? "tab active" : "tab"}
              onClick={() => handleSelectTab(tab)}
              onDoubleClick={() => handleDoubleClick(tab)}
            >
              {tab.name}
            </button>
          )}
        </li>
      );
    });
    return <ul>{allTabs}</ul>;
  };

  const handleSelectTab = (tab) => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      currentTab: {
        id: tab.id,
        name: tab.name,
        content: tab.content
      },
      editTabNameMode: false
    });
    saveUserDash(username+1, state)
    window.location.reload(false)
  };
  
  const handleAddTab = () => {
    const newTabObject= ({
      id: `${id}`,
      name: `Dashboard ${state.tabs.length + 1}`
    })

    setState({
      ...state,
      tabs: [...state.tabs, newTabObject],
      currentTab: newTabObject,
      editTabNameMode: false
    });
  };

  const handleDeleteTab = (tabToDelete) => {
    const tabToDeleteIndex = state.tabs.findIndex(tab => tab.id === tabToDelete.id);
    const updatedTabs = state.tabs.filter((tab, index) => {
      return index !== tabToDeleteIndex;
    });
    const previousTab = state.tabs[tabToDeleteIndex-1] || state.tabs[tabToDeleteIndex+1] || {};
    setState({
      tabs: updatedTabs,
      currentTab: previousTab,
      editTabNameMode: false,
    });
    localStorage.removeItem(tabToDelete.id)
  };

  const handleContentChange = (e) => {
    const updatedTabs = state.tabs.map((tab) => {
      if (tab.name === state.currentTab.name) {
        return {
          ...tab,
          content: e.target.value
        };
      } else {
        return tab
      }
    });

    setState({
      ...state, 
      tabs:updatedTabs,
      currentTab: {
        ...state.currentTab,
        content: e.target.value
      }
    })
  }

  const tabContent = () => {
    if ( state.currentTab.content === undefined ){
      return (
        <div>
            <div>
              <Dash id={state.currentTab.id} />
            </div>
        </div>
      )
    } else{
      return state.currentTab.content
    }
  }

  return(
    <div className=".container">
      <div className="well">
        <button className=".add-tab-button"  onClick={handleAddTab}>
          <i className="text-primary fas fa-plus-square" /> Add Dashboard
        </button>
        {createTabs()}
        <h3 style={{ textAlign: "center"}}>{state.currentTab.name}</h3>
        <div value={state.currentTab.content} className="tab-content" onChange={handleContentChange}>
          {tabContent()}
          {state.currentTab.id ? (
            <div>
              <br/>
              <button onClick={() => handleDeleteTab(state.currentTab)}>
                Delete
              </button>
            </div>          
          ) : (
            ""
          )}          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

getUserDash and saveUserDash functions;

```
//function to get user layout from LS
export const getUserDash = (key) => {
    try {
        const serialisedState = localStorage.getItem(key);
        if (serialisedState === null) {
          return ({
            tabs: [{id:'Welcome Page', name:'Guide to Use', content:'Welcome Dashboard'}],
            currentTab: {id:'Welcome Page', name:'Guide to Use', content:'Welcome Dashboard'},
            editTabNameMode: false
          });
        }
        return JSON.parse(serialisedState);
    } catch (error) {
      return ({
        tabs: [{id:'Welcome Page', name:'Guide to Use', content:'Welcome Dashboard'}],
        currentTab: {id:'Welcome Page', name:'Guide to Use', content:'Welcome Dashboard'},
        editTabNameMode: false
      });
    }
}

//function to save user layout to LS
export const saveUserDash = (layoutName, state) => {
    try {
        const serialisedState = JSON.stringify(state);
        localStorage.setItem(layoutName, serialisedState);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("local storage error")
    }
}
```

Comment: When you set the state, you are triggering a re-render. why do you need to force a reload? It should happen with the rerender, no?

Comment: I thought that but for some reason when I switch tab, the tab content is not updating. When I implemented the forced reload, the content changes but a second for the page to reload

Comment: If you have to refresh to see changes then it's usually due to a mutation of state.  But there is so much in this code that I just don't understand.  Like what on earth you are doing with a deep copy and adding `1` to a `string` here `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(getUserDash(username + 1))`.  You have an `onChange` and a `value` on a `div`.  Is there a reason that you are using `localStorage` at all here?  I think I will need to see the `getUserDash` and `saveUserDash` functions in order to figure this out.

Comment: Also you can make life a lot easier for yourself by storing the current tab's id only instead of the whole object.  You don't want to have to update in two places.  You can get the object by looking up the id in the array of all tabs.

Comment: @lallen6 I've got it working with `localStorage` https://codesandbox.io/s/editable-tabs-with-localstorage-p6r7n?file=/src/App.tsx  There's a few things I would like to tweak before I write an answer.

Comment: So I wanted to persist the state of the tabs to local storage so that when a user switches off/onto the app or signs out/in their layouts are preserved. The reason I did this with username + 1 is that something else in storage is already stored under the username. Looking at this now, it shouldn't be a problem to just use a string like "user dashboards" for this. I have  edited the post with the local storage functions. Thanks for your help,  still a bit of a novice when it comes to react so any advice is very useful!

Comment: @LindaPaiste I've just looked into your code sandbox and seen it's all in typescript, is there a simple way to convert this to js so I can implement it in my app? Thanks